# Get USDT TRC20 wallet address from 12 words of back up keys

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, web3py

I am wondering how to generate my USDT TRC20 wallet address from recovery phrase which is 12 words.

I cam up with this library mnemonic and am able to get to the seed but don't know how to go further.

```
from mnemonic import Mnemonic

mnemon = Mnemonic('english')
words = 'lucky labor rally law toss orange weasel try surge meadow type crumble proud slide century'
seed = mnemon.to_seed(words)

print(seed)
```